# jquery tabulator in Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-ui, npm, tabulator

I'm having trouble creating a tabulator in a javascript module in my Node.js app.  I was able to follow the quick start directions to define the tabulator in my html file, but when I try to do the same thing in a javascript module I get an error that say "tabulator() is not a method".  I also created a jquery-ui slider to be sure that part works.

I've installed jquery, jquery-ui and jquery.tabulator like this:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install jquery-ui-dist --save
npm install jquery.tabulator --save
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="tabulator"></div>
```

And my javascript looks like this:

```
const $ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = $;
const jqueryui = require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min');
const jquerytabulator = require('jquery.tabulator');

...

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').slider();        // this works and I get a slider on the page
    $('#tabulator').tabulator();  // this line gets an error
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, as of version 3.1.5 this has now been fixed.

http://olifolkerd.github.io/tabulator/docs/3.1/

Answer (score 0):

There is a tabulator demo project on github, called [MMM-Tabulator](https://github.com/E3V3A/MMM-Tabulator). Apparently showing you how to use Tabulator using either plain HTML or Node. However, the project seem to rely on using the [MagicMirror](https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror) framework.